# Adding WMTS with PyQGIS in QGIS standalone

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, wmts

I am trying to add WMTS into standalone QGIS. I am able to create project and with no issue adding vector or raster layer but when it comes to WMTS I am just getting layer into project but it is not loaded and I can not even open settings for it.
On my personal PC I can with below code add it without issues but on Linux Server where this code should run I am not able to load it properly.
Could it issue with proxy?

```
projectName = 'wms_load'
project = QgsProject.instance()
urlWithParams = 'crs=EPSG:3857&dpiMode=7&format=image/png&layers=geolandbasemap&styles=normal&tileMatrixSet=google3857&url=https://www.basemap.at/wmts/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml'

rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(urlWithParams, 'geolandbasemap', 'wms')
if not rlayer.isValid():
  print("Layer failed to load!")
else:
    print('Layer loaded')
project.addMapLayer(rlayer) 

project = QgsProject.instance()
project.write()

qgs.exitQgis()
```